# how to update one only one field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a small project using **Django / Rest Framework**. I would like to update my table ( since I have already some rows ) I want to update only one column `status`  but I get an error about other fields are required:

how can I update only one field, exactly `status`, I want to set the status to 1, without updating the other columns,
**(Django keep telling me other fields are required like title, mobile)**

this is my code :

```
obj = Task.objects.filter(id=tasks['id']).first()
       serializer = self.serializer_class(obj, data = {'status':1})
       if serializer.is_valid():
          serializer.save()
```

Comment: Use a `patch` method, not `put`.

Comment: what is the difference between patch and put

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the official Django documentation, serializer must passed values for all required fields. in order to omit this behavior you need to assign `True` to the `partial` attributes.

```py
obj = Task.objects.filter(id=tasks['id']).first()
serializer = self.serializer_class(obj, data = {'status':1}, partial=True)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
```

Comment: This is how it works as you mentioned, by passing `partial=True`, but it's better to also mention that this always associated with `PATCH` request